# Grub menu not showing after installing ubuntu 15.04 in dual boot with windows

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, uefi, 15.04

I have a lenovo g50-80 windows 8.1 is preinstalled in uefi mode. I changed the mode to legacy mode then installed ubuntu 15.04. but even after installing it boot menu was not coming. Then I changed the boot order to legacy first.

Thereafter, when I loaded system grub menu came but after the login screen in ubuntu it showd nothing. Then I restarted and selected the windows option from grub menu but windows was corrupted I had to recover it using recovery drive.

Ubuntu 15 i

Comment: You really need to have both systems installed in UEFI boot mode to dual boot. UEFI & BIOS are not really compatible and once you start booting in one mode you cannot switch. Or once you load grub in BIOS mode you cannot boot Windows in UEFI mode. Post link to Summary report from Boot-Repair. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info If just black screen issue: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: I have deleted the ubuntu partition, can u tell me how can i install ubuntu in uefi mode. Because boot from usb option is not showing in boot menu in uefi mode.

Comment: UEFI will show two boot options, one clearly UEFI: and name of flash drive and the other just the name of flash drive. You may have to turn secure boot off, but should not have to, or may have to change UEFI settings to specifically allow booting from flash drive. Some systems like Acer require you to set a UEFI password(never lose that) to open up those settings.

Comment: CAUTION: do not use any of the auto install options on reinstalling. I think 15.04 has the fix, but best to use Something Else install option. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1265192

Comment: possible duplicate of [Attempted Installing Ubuntu on Windows 8.1 UEFI, Confused about booting in UEFI, Legacy Mode](http://askubuntu.com/questions/597325/attempted-installing-ubuntu-on-windows-8-1-uefi-confused-about-booting-in-uefi)

Comment: Go back into your firmware setup utility and reverse the change you made to enable BIOS/CSM/legacy support. Doing that created your problem. Unfortunately, a lot of sites tell you to do this, but it's Bad Advice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grub not showing on startup for Windows 8.1 Ubuntu 13.10 Dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371559/grub-not-showing-on-startup-for-windows-8-1-ubuntu-13-10-dual-boot)

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu will install perfectly fine on the G80 using UEFI mode. Do the following to install Ubuntu properly:

1. Return the laptop to the original boot setting, not legacy
2. Download [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) to create the bootable USB drive (which works with UEFI and MBR)
3. Reboot with flash drive connected (pressing F8 for boot options or F1 for BIOS setup *whichever allows you to boot from USB*)
4. Install Ubuntu as normal (by creating custom partitions "only need root '/' and swap partition or '/home' if so desired") or choosing "along side Windows". This would be the quick way to get Ubuntu installed on the computer.

Also whenever you remove the partitions for a Ubuntu installation, because grub is installed you have to run a Windows installer to fix the boot for Windows. When you insert the Windows installation media choose "Repair my computer>Troubleshoot>Advanced>Command prompt". Run the following command:

`bootrec.exe /fixmbr`

This will fix the Windows boot loader so Windows boots right up after restarting, if you don't have something else installed that requires a boot loader.

I would suggest starting over with Ubuntu if you can to properly install it. Get booted up into the installer, remove the old partitions (not the Windows ones), and then recreating them again. This would ensure a fresh install of Ubuntu.